# Rails Syntax for entering data in sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been following this tutorial, http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users?version=3.2#top,
and I tried this in the rails console

```
User.new(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhart@example.com")
SyntaxError: compile error
```

but when I tried this it worked:

```
User.new(:name=> "Michael Hartl", :email=>"mhart@example.com")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhart@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I am using rails 3.2.1, which I guess this is the problem, but why change the syntax to something more complicated like, `:<variable>=>` instead of `<variable>:` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't type it correctly.

`User.new(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhart@example.com")`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It was "User.new(name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhart@example.com")" ! So the question remains#

Comment: If you aren't using Ruby 1.9+ then you can't use the new hash syntax.